# How to avoid strings containing parts of a search string from appearing when using the 'in' operator?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, operators

I know there are several posts out there about how to find a substring within a string but I have the opposite problem. How to I avoid strings containing parts of my search string from appearing when I use the 'in' operator?

For example, I want all lists containing `'kmt2d'` to return `True`. However, lists containing `'set2d'` also return `True` because of the `'t2d'` common substring between the two.

Here is an example of my code:

```
listone = ['kmt2d']
listtwo = ['set2d', 'hgt', 'kmt2d']
listthree = []

for i in listtwo:
    for k in listone:
        if k in i:
            listthree.append(True)
        else:
            listthree.append(False)
```

The output for listthree appears as:

```
listthree = [True, False, True]
```

However, I would want it to be:

```
listthree = [False, False, True]
```

Is there something wrong with my code or are there any other operators which could help me achieve the same result?

Comment: [mcve] please. The code you posted doesn't run, and even if it did it wouldn't produce the output you claim it produces. Also, it looks like you want to do equality checking (that is, `==`), not membership testing (`in`).

Comment: If you want to find exact matches, use the `==` (equality) operator in your if condition. (change `if k in i` to `if k == i`)

Comment: I corrected your syntax and moved the `listthree` initialization before the `for` loop -- this is required to let it accumulate three values.  The program then runs as you want.  I don't see a simple change that allows your current code to produce the output you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
one = ['kmt2d']
two = ['set2d', 'hgt', 'kmt2d']
three = [item for item in two if item in one]

# which is:
three = []
for item in two:
    if item in one:
        three.append(item)
```

In your 2nd loop you loop through the second list which means the `in` operator scans the string, not whether it exists in the list. Do away with the 2nd loop and use `in` just to test whether that item appears in the list without actually scanning inside the strings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine:

```
listone = ['kmt2d']
listtwo = ['set2d', 'hgt', 'kmt2d']
listthree = []

for i in listtwo:
    for k in listone:
        if k in i:
            listthree.append(True)
        else:
            listthree.append(False)
```

**Output**:

```
listthree = [False, False, True]
```